# A different suffix for each line on Highstock/Highcharts with Thingspeak source

Tags: highcharts, iot

I've got the code for Highcharts in combination with Thingspeak from here:

```
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=213058.0
```

My problem is, I am not able to implement the different suffix into the code :-(. I've tried a lot, but I dont understand the mechanism behind the Java code.

I've tried some things, but result is, I only have one datafield for the first series but not for the other series...

Formatter function is on line 246.
My different yAxies on line 286.
How can formatter decide which yAxies do actual series use?

Maybe somebody have fun to help me?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/cbmj8rku/
```

Best regards, David

Answer (score 0):

Each series is assigned to one yAxis. You can detect which series uses which axis for example by axis title:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var points = this.points,
            title,
            result = '';

        Highcharts.each(points, function(p) {
            result += p.y;
            title = p.series.yAxis.axisTitle.textStr;

            if (title === 'yAxis1') {
                result += 'suffix1<br>'
            } else if (title === 'yAxis1') {
                result += 'suffix2<br>'
            } else {
                result += 'suffix2<br>'
            }
        });

        return result
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ncvtxoke/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/cbmj8rku/20/

```
              formatter: function() {
            var d = new Date(this.x + (myOffset*60000));
            var _Min = (d.getMinutes()<10) ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
            var _Sec = (d.getSeconds()<10) ? '0' + d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds();
            var s = d.getHours() + ':' + _Min + ':' + _Sec + '<br/>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
              s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ' <b>' + this.y + this.series.yAxis.userOptions.labels.suffix + '</b>';this.series.tooltipOptions.valueSuffix[this.point.index];
            });

            return s;
          }
```